# PHP Mysqli selecting wrong column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query as below. When i run this in MYSQL workbench it is selecting the correct ID from consignment table but when i see the result in PHP it is selecting the ID from parcel table.

Any reason why it is doing so?

The valArray  variable has the ID from parcel table instead of consignment table.

Thanks

```
        SELECT *
        FROM consignment c
        inner join parcel p on c.id = p.consignment_id
        WHERE  c.date_booked >='2020-06-04' AND c.date_booked <='2020-06-04' AND p.hold='1'


        $rs = mysqli_query(self::$connection, $sql);
        $objectArray = array();
        while ($valArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
        {
            $objectArray[] = new $className($valArray);
        }
```

Comment: What's the output of $valArray. Also, what is $className? Do parcel and consignment both has id columns? You're using SELECT *, it would be cleaner to SELECT parcel.id as parcel_id so you don't have column clashes.

Comment: If you use `SELECT *` while joining two tables that has some of the same names, you might run into trouble. Its better then to explicitly define which columns your are selecting

Comment: Nothing good ever came from `SELECT *`. Just select (and qualify, and, if necessary, alias) the columns you actually want.

Comment: As mentioned above by users, explicitly mentioning column names along with alias worked. Thanks!!!